# HTTPretty test hanging on Travis

Tags: python, python-3.4, travis-ci, nose, httpretty

While making [python-intercom](/things/python-intercom/) Python 3 compatible, I ran into an issue on [Travis](http://travis-ci.org).

The `nosetests` command doesn't appear to exit when run on Python 3.4 (it behaves as expected on Python 2.7). I narrowed it down to tests that use [HTTPretty](http://falcao.it/HTTPretty) and created a [small project](https://github.com/jkeyes/travis-nose) to highlight the issue, and to publish the results of a [failed build](https://travis-ci.org/jkeyes/travis-nose/builds/56028754):

```
$ nosetests
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.061s
OK

No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially
indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

The build has been terminated
```

Right now I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the latest release of `httppretty` in Python 3.4. I had the same problem and then I **downgraded it to 0.8.6**. It seems to be because of some `Warning` being raised described in this [github issue](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/issues/228).

Comment: That's interesting, as I don't see the problem locally on OS X. I'll try the downgrade. Thanks.

Comment: Weird, I do see the problem locally in os x as well. Perhaps you're not using python 3.4 locally? Hope downgrading helps

Comment: I'm running Python 3.4.3 (installed by Homebrew). Downgrading worked, thanks.

Comment: What version of http pretty have you installed locally?